# How to move a JTextField or JButton to the left

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, textfield

Lets say you wan't get rid of a `button` if you just `setVisible` to `false` it will simply disappear, but it doesn't look to good, so i figured that it would be cool if the `button/textfield` would swiftly move to the left and when it hits the corner it would disappear.
How could i do that?

Comment: You mean drag&drop a component?

Comment: Sounds more like something along the lines of a horizontal version of jQuery's slideUp/Down transition, but for Swing

Comment: @jonhopkins - I don't know what JQuery slideOut is, but i guess you are thinking about the right thing.

Comment: @user2794550 it's just a visual effect that can be used while adding or removing elements from a webpage. It's a JavaScript thing though, so useless here. But from your description, it sounds like you want a similar effect. And if someone knows how to do it, I'd like to see that answer too :)

Comment: i think that you have to move a component with a swing timer, and when reaces the border the setvisible(false)..and call repaint() revalidate().. for each "x"milliseconds, im not sure if i am right, wait for swing gurus :D

Comment: There's nothing pre-made for that in swing, but there are third party libraries, such as the [timing framework](https://java.net/projects/timingframework).

Comment: Please have a look at [Sliding Layout](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/sliding-layout), hopefully this might be able to satisfy your needs :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the componenet is in a JFrame or JPanel you can simply remove it with the remove method:

```
frame.remove(button1);
panel.remove(button1);
repaint();
```

Or get the content Pane and use the remove method.

Else if you want to move it out of the window to have that "disappearing" effect, as far for my short experience in swing is that you might will need to set the layout to null and use:

```
button1.setLocation(x,y);
```

or

```
button1.setBounds(x,y,width,height);
```

But if you want to see the button slide slowly to the left or w/e direction you want to go, you may wanna look into timers and threads,see whichever suits your need to simulate this kind of effect, watch out for memory leaks though by writing good code. =/